# KIWI TCMS - Test case content deleted when changing status

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I have installed Kiwi-tcms locally as a docker container on an Ubuntu server.
Everything works as expected except when I want to write a new test case.
Here are the steps I used:

**Prerequisites:**

A testplan already created

**Steps:**

1. login to Kiwi
2. select a testplan from the dashboard
3. click on "Write new case" in the cases tab
4. fill mandatory field
5. click on "Save" and go back to the testplan
6. go to "Reviewing cases"
7. change the status of the test case previously created from "Proposed" to "Confirmed"

**Expected result:**

Test case is updated with the status chosen

**Actual result:**

Test case content deleted: title and content deleted but test case created.

**More info:**

I cannot reproduce this bug when I edit the test case and change the status inside the description.

I have not been able to reproduce this bug with the online demo so I guess there's something wrong with my docker configuration or application configuration.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug which affects the latest available version. Already fixed here: https://github.com/kiwitcms/Kiwi/issues/1318

will be released in the next update.